# Are there any differences in performance between non-blocking IO request and blocking IO request wrapped in Future?

Tags: scala

Suppose that Play framework is used,
are these methods effectively the same in terms of performance?

```
def requestA(): Future[Response] = Future {
  blockingIoRequest()
}


def requestB(): Future[Response] = {
  nonBlockingIoRequest()
}
```

Comment: Yes. The blocking one will block one thread of your thread pool (which is powering your ExecutionContext) whereas the non-blocking will not.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

- using blocking requests means that only one request may be active at any time in any one thread (because it blocks while waiting for activity)
- using blocking requests is generally easier than non-blocking requests (asynchronous programming tends to be more complicated)
- you could create 1 thread per request but threads have overhead and are extremely inefficient compared to the non-blocking solutions;
- non-blocking requests could handle a much larger volume of requests: it could scale to hundreds of thousands in a single process - but the code becomes a little bit more complicated

Nonblocking I/O will give you the best performance (thousands of requests) at the expense of being the most difficult to understand and implement correctly.

Basically everything boils down to performance vs. programming complexity.

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

In case you described, it depends more on the fact which `ExecutionContext` you use, then blocking or non blocking operation you invoke.

Basically, if in case of

```
def requestA(): Future[Response] = Future {
  blockingIoRequest()
}
```

you will use same `ExecutionContext` which is used in controllers (for instance for `Action.async` handling), `Filters` or other request handling places, then yes - it will impact performance, because blocking the thread inside such `Future` execution, will impact other incoming request handling. Hence, it is recommended to perform such blocking operations inside another `ExecutionContext` intended to be used for blocking operation (like DB access, network operations etc.)

Please, take a look for more details at doc page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools

Hope this helps!